# Concerning opinion-based/broad questions and alternatives

Tags: discussion

I understand the need for this, but I feel like it's really a shame that questions seeking opinions from this extremely knowledgeable community are automatically downvoted/closed/put on hold. I think a lot of people deal with large scale projects, and would appreciate being pointed in the right direction by people who have a lot more experience. Internet is very scarce on message boards with helpful and experimented users like Stack Overflow. If not here, where is one supposed to go for direction on a new project?

Comment: Generally such people have colleagues or classmates. You don't do large scale projects alone.

Comment: @Gimby That's a pretty bold assumption. A lot of people prefer working alone, and if they're working with, say, classmates, chances are they're on the same level as them.

Comment: It's like asking _What should I code in C# or VB.NET?_. It's just not answerable and would cause a lot of opinions to blow up on the question. Or _Which database should I use, MySQL, SQL-Server, SQLite, MS Access or Oracle to store my data?_ Nobody can answer that but you.

Comment: @SimonBesozzi If you're working on it alone it's almost certainly, by definition, not a large scale project.  A really *large* scale project takes more man-hours to create than a single human's lifespan.

Comment: I think large is pretty subjective. I think it's relative to the effective work-force. I consider a project that could take a single person 500+ hours to be a large scale project, if done alone. That's not the point of the post though.

Comment: @SimonBesozzi times have changed them, when I was in school people varied in skill level right from day one ranging from people with programming experience to people who picked informatics because they didn't know what else to do. Other than that: what Servy said.

Comment: @Gimby actually you can if you considering building a video game like an RPG a large scale project. not all Indie Devs have friends who can help them

Comment: I have always found it extremely ironic that a site that is run by engineers, developers, and designers has such a HORRIBLE UX  where new users are concerned. I mean, isn't the whole point (or at least one of the main pillars) of web app design to ensure that the user experience is pleasant from START to finish. Show me a first time poster who says their experience was pleasant, and I'll show you a liar. You all know what I'm talking about. I do think this site serves a very valuable purpose, but I wouldn't call it user friendly in any sense of the term.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow is not a forum where you can discuss about "MySQL vs MongoDB", or other debat dealing with subjective opinions.

Is only deals with **questions and answers**. That's all.

You can't really answer a question that is too broad (too many answers), or primarily opinion-based. That is why we prefer to close it.

I think the primarily opinion-based flag explain well this, so I quote it:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert
>   experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost
>   entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific
>   expertise.

---

<sub>I'm not saying that questions about "MySQL vs MongoDB" are bad, but there are others blogs/forums discussing about this, and it is simply not the purpose of Stack Overflow.</sub>

Comment: That's the thing though. In all other threads about this issue on Meta, people refer to ''There are other forums to... etc.'', but no one has a concrete example, because none of those small scales forums have the reach and expertise of stack communities.

Comment: @SimonBesozzi And that's not a coincidence.  SO is the way that it is precisely *because* of the questions that it allows and doesn't allow.  Experts come to SO to share their expertise because they know that there are going to be quality questions with objectively verifiable answers, rather than random people just shouting their opinions.

Comment: I didn't say it was, I meant that all of these other resources don't offer the same level of expertise as Stack.

Comment: @Simon it is a catch 22 actually. No other forums have expertise because they allow this type of Q.... stack has that expertise partly because of their quality standard, which blocks this type of Q...

Comment: To me, a simple resolution to that issue would be to have another Stack community where users could ask for guidance in specific project. I understand SO might not be the place, but surely there's a way to make use of Stack's users' experience through their opinions

Comment: @SimonBesozzi They tried that.  It ended exactly as you would expect, it was an awful place full of low quality content that nobody wanted to use, so it died.  They've learned from their mistake and aren't planning to repeat it.

Comment: But again... the experts that flooded here did so (some of them at least) BECAUSE these questions aren't allowed. Seems like a 'bait n switch' if we suddenly allow thwm

Comment: @SimonBesozzi People want to ask opinionated and broad questions here because this is where the expertise is, not realizing that those types of questions are what actively drive away expertise and lower quality.  By allowing them, you're driving away the very expertise you want to answer them.  It's a self-defeating cycle.